# Fill empty rows between values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to carry down values from a preceding row until it hits another new value.  LAG does not work because it only fills 1 row and I might have anywhere from 1 to 12 rows depending on an order number.

`ColumnA` is my row number, `columnB` is column that I need to fill until it hits the next nonblank. Any help is much appreciated because I'm out of ideas.

Row would be like this

```
Columna  Columb  ColumnC  ColumnD
12       Yarn    Yellow   Coarse
13               Yellow   Coarse
14       Needles Size G   Steel
15               Size H   Wood
16               Size Y   Wood
17       Hooks   Fish     Steel
18               Whale    Steel
18               Dolphin  Steel
19               Mermaid  Steel
```

Answer (score 0):

Given field A is an uninterrupted sequence..

```
Table
A        B        C        D
12       Yarn     Yellow   Coarse 
13                Yellow   Coarse 
14       Needles  Size G   Steel 
15                Size H   Wood 
16                Size Y   Wood 
17       Hooks    Fish     Steel 
18                Whale    Steel 
19                Dolphin  Steel 
20                Mermaid  Steel
```

My First Pass At It

```
Select 
   T1.A
   COALESCE(T2.A,T1.B) as B,
   T1.C,
   T1.D 

From
    Table as T1
    LEFT JOIN Table as T2 ON T2.A = T1.A -1
```

New Answer

```
Select 
   T1.A
   Coalesce(
       T1.B,
       (
           Select top 1 B 
           FROM Table 
           WHERE A < T1.A 
            and B IS Not Null
           ORDER BY A DESC
       )
    ) as B,
    T1.C,
    T1.D 
FROM    
    Table as T1
```

Comment: Looking at this again, I gave an incorrect answer.  I'll ponder this.

Comment: Select 
   T1.A
   Coalesce(
 T1.B,
 (Select B 
  FROM Table 
         WHERE A = T1.A 
            and B IS Not Null
 )
   ) as B,
   T1.C,
   T1.D 

From
    Table as T1